# Understanding automatic text formatting in the Wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I'm a big Wordpress fan because of its easy-to-use admin interface but one thing has been bugging me from the very beginning:

**Why does the text editor remove paragraphs and line breaks?**

Surely maintaining basic formatting such as paragraphs or line breaks is a **basic requirement** in all CMS systems. It's hard to believe that Wordpress has remained the most popular content management system on the market when it's **not even able to maintain basic text formatting**.

I've searched numerous forums - all of which recommend the TinyMCE Advanced plugin or manipulating the wpautop() function - but nowhere is there a clear explanation of:

1.why Wordpress removes paragraphs and line breaks in the first place;

2.what is best practice for stopping the text editor from behaving this way.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: If I make a simple content item in WP I get paragraph tags (e.g. `<p>This is a start of content.</p>
<p>This is a second sentence.</p>`)  Are you loading some plugin that is doing this modification to the content?

Comment: It sounds like there may be a 3rd party plugin that is messing with your editor's default behavior. Could you share your results on a vanilla install?

Comment: Interesting. Could this be a Visual Composer problem?